# How to install Python 3.6.4 on Windows 8.1 Pro?

Tags: python, windows-8.1, python-3.6, python-install

Python installed but all the required folders are missing on the python folder.

[image]

Comment: That's the folder of the start menu, not where python is installed.

Comment: Yes but on this path There should be folder like Scripts,libs,pip etc should be there which i tried it on the windows 7 , it was there

Comment: Nope, usually python installs in `C:\Python36\ ` and not in a route containing `Start Menu`.

Comment: But there is no such folder path is created on my local system, can you please help me out, i am stucked with it

Answer (score 0):

You can find the files in your C drive, I've installed Python 2.7 so it's C:\Python27, it might be C:\Python36 for you.

Comment: No i've installed 3.6.4 but there is no such folder created. Have you installed python 3.6.4 on windows 8.1 . Help me out